# Write a rvalue integer in a ostream as a binary value

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, ostream, rvalue

I'm trying to output an integer as binary in a `std::ostream`.

The first thing I tried was:

```
int MyInt(){return 42;}
//...
std::ostream out; //not actually this but any ostream will do
out<<MyInt();
```

This of course converts the `int` to a character string which isn't what I want.

I also found a way to make it work:

```
int value=MyInt();
out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(int));
```

This outputs what I want however I have to use a temporary to hold the value while using the function directly like this:

```
 out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(MyInt())), sizeof(int));
```

Will fail to compile because I can't take the address of a `rvalue` (unless it's bound to a const reference).

This made me try that:

```
out.write(&(const char&)(MyInt()), sizeof(int));
```

However while it does preserve the smallest byte the other ones are garbage. The results are also probably implementation-defined as far as I know so not a recommended solution even if it were to work.

A `union` can solve the problem and is probably nicer than a temporary variable.

```
union IntConverter{
    int i;
    char c[sizeof(int)];
    IntConverter(int in) :i(in){}
};
out.write(IntConverter(MyInt()).c, sizeof(int));
```

However, I would like to avoid having to write more code if possible and I'm out of ideas so I am asking if there is a better solution to solve this problem.

Comment: I assume "out << std::hex << MyInt()" won't get you what you want?

Comment: `std::hex` will write the value in hexadecimal but it's still text. The second and last example give me the correct output (4 bytes written, first byte is 42 and the others 0).

Comment: So what's so bad about using a temporary? You're creating a temporary anyway with the union. It's certainly easier to read than the union.

Comment: You are spending too much energy on a seemingly non-existent problem. Use `int value = MyInt(); out.write(...);` and move on to bigger and better things.

Comment: Since I'm writing more than one value setting the temporary every time would be more a pain. Last solution can be templated to work with anything which is why so far I'm going with that. I still don't really like it.

Comment: Reading a different field of the union other than the one you set is undefined behavior, and if it works will give different results depending on the endianess of the system. You need to use bitshifting to populate the char array from your int.

Comment: I know it depends on endianess however I am pretty sure the results should be identical to the cast of the integer value pointer to a `char*`. I don't have endianess problems for now (everything using little-endian). While `union` do have implementation-defined behaviour, because they use the same storage for both values I think that as long as the program that reads it back uses the same implementation there should be no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to easily output an int in binary, I would use a wrapper class with a friend `operator <<`. It could easily be templated to accept integral of different sizes. For example:

```
template<typename T>
class BinInt {
private:
    T i;

public:
    BinInt(T i): i(i) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const BinInt& b) {
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&(b.i)), sizeof(T));
        return os;
    }
    T val() {
        return i;
    }
};
```

You can use it as simply as:

```
BinInt<int> bi(0x41424344);
BinInt<short> bs(0x4546);
std::cout << "Val:" << bi.val() << " - repr:" << bi << std::endl;
std::cout << "Val:" << bs.val() << " - repr:" << bs << std::endl;
```

and on a 32 bits little endian it gives:

```
Val:1094861636 - repr:DCBA
Val:17734 - repr:FE
```

Comment: That option is nicer than the union one. I'll accept if nobody comes up with something better in the next days. It's not exactly what I want but it's a good improvement over what I was doing.